# How do I find my distro name via the command line?

Tags: shell-script, software-installation

Is there any command that outputs your distro name like this: CentOS Ubuntu,etc.?

I am looking to make a script that will execute a different batch of commands for each distro and I need to know how to do such a thing with a command.

Comment: please don't.  create separate packages for different distros (or rely on the distros themselves to package your software if it's FOSS).  encouraging your users to bypass their distro's packaging software is encouraging them to break their systems.  I know that's fashionable these days with some devs who like to pretend that THEIR software is the only important software on any system, but it's still a bad idea - it's a reversion to the bad old days of software installation before decent packaging and policies, and before distros.

Comment: its not a software package its a shell script for steamcmd to automatically install it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a shell script fragment that does the job:

```sh
# try various methods, in order of preference, to detect distro
# store result in variable '$distro'
if type lsb_release >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
   distro=$(lsb_release -i -s)
elif [ -e /etc/os-release ] ; then
   distro=$(awk -F= '$1 == "ID" {print $2}' /etc/os-release)
elif [ -e /etc/some-other-release-file ] ; then
   distro=$(ihavenfihowtohandleotherhypotheticalreleasefiles)
fi

# convert to lowercase
distro=$(printf '%s\n' "$distro" | LC_ALL=C tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')

# now do different things depending on distro
case "$distro" in
   debian*)  commands-for-debian ;;
   centos*)  commands-for-centos ;;
   ubuntu*)  commands-for-ubuntu ;;
   mint*)    commands-for-mint ;;
   *)        echo "unknown distro: '$distro'" ; exit 1 ;;
esac
```

You may want a more useful default (`*`) action in the `case` statement than printing an error message and aborting.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas I liked your first edit but is there any difference between `tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'` and `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` if `LC_ALL=C`?  Doesn't setting the locale to C undermine the point of using `[:upper:]` and `[:lower:]`?  aside from it being better self-documenting code, that is.

Comment: Unix is case sensitive, so its important to correct such thing

Comment: @ErikLindGou-Said uh, yes, of course it is.  That's why I converted $distro to lowercase in the first place.  Check the edit history.  That's not what I'm asking SC about.

Comment: oh ok nevermind then

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

- `cat /etc/os-release` or `lsb_release -a`for Debian
- `cat /etc/*-release` or `lsb_release -a` for CentOS/Ubuntu.

Comment: `cat /proc/version` does not do the job.  it displays the kernel version, possibly including compilation details including gcc version and maybe distro.   `/etc/os-release` exists in debian and derivatives (like ubuntu) and is in the `base-files` package (which is an `Essential` package, installed by default and can not be removed without a LOT of stuffing around, potentially breaking the system).   `awk -F= '$1 == "ID" {print $2}' /etc/os-release`

Comment: @cas : My debian box displays `cat /proc/version` as `Linux version 2.6.32-5-xen-amd64 (Debian 2.6.32-48squeeze17)` where `squeeze` is Debian Distribution. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: so?  That's what happens to be compiled into the kernel.  There's no guarantee that any other kernel will happen to contain the string "Debian" - that may be a likely occurrence if compiled on a debian system using debian-packaged compilers and tools, but is by no means guaranteed.   `/etc/os-release` **IS** guaranteed to be on any debian system, and contains exactly the information requested by the OP.

Comment: @cas : Ah, Thank you for your information. I have updated my answer.

Comment: BTW, `lsb_release -a` usually works on debian too, as the `lsb-release` package is depended upon by several other packages, including commonly installed ones such as `command-not-found` (BTW a default non-minimalist debian install with desktop environment etc WILL install `command-not-found` and `lsb-release`.  You have to go out of your way to NOT install the `command-not-found` package).

Comment: @cas : Yes, that works too.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command :

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

or

```
lsb_release -a
```

Finding just the distribution name and version:

```
cat /etc/issue
```